# Fedora 32 stuck in boot and wont boot after installling NVIDIA Driver

Tags: linux, fedora, nvidia

Having problem in using nvidia in fedora.

Fedora Kernal Details as below,

> kernel: 5.7.14-200.fc32.x86_64
> Fedora : 32/ 64-bit
> NVIDIA: GEForce GTX 1600Ti

I tried steps given [here](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/).

After successfully installing, stuck at fedora boot menu for infinite period.

Tried nvidia driver version for Linux - 440.10, 430.09, 450.57 nothing helped in resolving the boot freeze unless i uninstall the nvidia graphics card driver by tunnelling into terminally from boot instead of GUI mode.

The `lspci` command returns below :

> `lspci |grep -E "VGA|3D"`
> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] (rev a1)

Couldn't find proper match / solution for the above said problem.

Any help appreciated because this will make NVIDIA void in laptop if i use linux.

Is there bug with nvidia for linux kernal or

Comment: Ask here instead https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-unix-graphics/linux/148

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Thanks

Comment: Can you hit control-alt-F3 after it has been at the boot prompt for a while and get a console, or is it wedged?  Does control-alt-delete work?

Comment: Ctrl+alt+del reboots!!

control-alt-F3 doesnt do anything just stuck in fedora logo still

only way i can enter into machine is by login into console mode (3) using boot menu->e and change boot mode

Comment: Adding BusID  to xorg.conf file as said [here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/fedora-32-stuck-in-boot-and-wont-boot-after-installling-nvidia-driver/146573/4?u=arvind_k)  solved the issue and system also shows NVIDIA as card in properties

Comment: @A.K Please add your soultion as an answer!